# if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

**I'm working on a serverinfo command in discord.js v13 and I don't know how to fix this error**

***ERROR:***

**[Photo Error]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcEem.png**

> **if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);**
> ^

> **RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.**

> **[Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_FIELD_VALUE'**

```
const { Client, MessageEmbed, Message } = require(`discord.js`);
const moment = require(`moment`)

module.exports = {
  name: "serverinfo",
  description: "Get server information",
  /**
  *
  * @param {Client} client 
  * @param {Message} message
  * @param {String[]} args
  */
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const guild = message.guild;
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(message.guild.name)
      .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL())
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .addField(`General Info`, [
        `ID: ${guild.id}`,
        `Name: ${guild.name}`,
        `Owner: ${guild.owner}`,
      ])
      .addField("Counts", [
        `Role: ${guild.roles.cache.size} roles`,
        `Channel: ${guild.channel.cache.size
        } total (Text: ${guild.channel.cache.filter(
          (ch) => ch.type === "text"
        ).size}, Voice: ${guild.channel.cache.filter(
          (ch) => ch.type === "Voice"
        )})`,
        `Emojis: ${guild.emojis.cache.size} (Regular: ${guild.emojis.cache.filter((e) => !e.animated).size
}, Animated: ${
  guild.emojis.cache.filter((e) => !e.animated).size
})`,
    ])
    .addField("Additional Information", [
      `Created: ${
  moment(guild.createdTimestamp).format(
    `LT`
  )
} ${ moment(guild.createdTimestamp).format(`LL`) } ${
  moment(
    guild.createdTimestamp
  ).fromNow()
} `,
      `Region: ${ guild.region } `,
      `Boost Tier: ${
  guild.premiumTier ? `Tier ${guild.premiumTier}` : "None"
} `,
      `Boost Count: ${guild.premiumSubscribtionCount || "0"}`,
    ]);

    message.channel.send({ embed });
  },
};
```

Comment: Please include the _whole_ error message (including the traceback). It would also be nice if you could indicate with a comment which line the error is reported to have originated from (if within your code).

Comment: I added a picture with error

Comment: For the future, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to [`.addField`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addField) must be a string, as your error message says:

> MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.

You pass an array, which is not a "non-empty string". I.e.

```
let embed = new MessageEmbed()
.addField('foo', 'bar')
```

is fine.

```
let embed = new MessageEmbed()
.addField('foo', ['bar', 'baz'])
```

is not.